# What if the first occurrence of a term for a glossary is plural?

Tags: glossaries

I am using the package glossaries in LaTeX. In the preamble I have

```
\newglossaryentry{error}
{
  name = error,
  description = {the difference between the actual value and the predicted value}
}
```

And in the text I have

> and $e$ is an $n x 1$ vector of errors

I would like to have a glossary item for error (in the singular).

If I use \gls{errors} it quite sensibly says that that has no entry.  If I use \gls{error}s then no glossary entry appears.

How can I do what I want?

Here is an MWE (it doesn't work, because of the problems described above).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}%Verbatim
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipdf]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thesection}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\pagestyle{plain}
\title{The General Linear Model: Assumptions, violations and remedies or What to do when your dependent variable won't behave}
\author{Peter Flom}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{error}
{
  name = error,
  description = {the difference between the actual value and the predicted value}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{Preface}\normalsize
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\pagestyle{plain}

This is a book about regression. 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}



\chapter{Introduction: The General Linear Model and its Assumptions}
  \section{The model}
  The general linear model (GLM) subsumes linear regression and ANOVA (these models are equivalent, if you do not know why, see Appendix A; in this book I will use the regression framework). It is one of the most commonly used statistical methods, used in thousands of papers and analyses in every field of science and business. The idea is that we have one dependent (or target, or outcome) variable that we want to model as a linear function of one or more independent variables. The dependent variable (DV) must be continuous. The independent variables (IV) can be categorical or continuous. The model can be written:
  \[
    Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \dots b_px_p + e
  \]
  where there are p independent variables.
  In matrix terms (for all the matrix knowledge you will need in this book see appendix B)
  \[
    Y = XB + e
  \]
  where $Y$ is an $n x 1$ vector of dependent variable, $X$ is an $n x p$ matrix of independent variables, $B$ is a $p x 1$ vector of parameters to be estimated and $e$ is an $n x 1$ vector of \gls{errors}.


\chapter{Glossary}
\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you specify a plural form and use `\glspl`? That would be the intended way for plurals of glossary entries according to the manual… (And as always: Please help us help you by making your code example a compilable MWE.)

Comment: The term is "error" not "errors" and using "errors" would just add to confusion on the part of readers. I'll try to make a full example.

Comment: So why don't you add `plural=errors` (it isn't even needed) and use `\glspl{error}` as suggested in the manual?

Comment: When I tried that, the glossary had no entries.

Comment: Have you run `makeglossaries` in between (just to be sure it is generated at all)?

Comment: For now, I solved it by changing the text slightly so that the first occurrence  is "error". Then the glossary prints fine.